# How do i make lists show top navigation when using managed metadata?

Tags: sharepoint-online, term-set, metadata-navigation

I have a site where I use managed metadata as navigation.
It works like a charm for pages.
BUT
When I add a list to my navigation it removes the top navigation item.

here is a rundown of how it is built:

[image]

"**Superusers**" and "**Support opening hours**" are pages.
"**Computer whitelist**" is a SharePoint list.

So when I set up my metadata navigation I can see the entire navigation ( 4 elements if I choose "**Superusers**" or "**support opening hours**" as shown on this picture:

[image]

My problem comes when I click on "**Computer whitelist**". It doesn't show the Top nav point ( IT ) it only shows the 3 elements that are on the same level in the navigation as shown on this picture:

[image]

So my question is how do I setup lists to show the entire navigation?
Or is this a limitation of metadata navigation?

EDIT: it is set to simple link as shown in the picture:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with simple link to list (**with relative url**)

[image: Simple link to list]

---Edit---

You have **absolute path** to list. Try with **relative path** to list.

example of absolute path> https://SITE/Shared Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx

Type just **/Shared Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx**

:)

Comment: that is already done.

Comment: Edited answer :)